# None-value in browseable API

Tags: django-rest-framework

In Django REST Framework, given a field in a Django model which has null=True and blank=True, and where the field is required=False in the serializer, is there any way to have the browseable API render the HTML dropdown with a blank value? Using JSON it is possible to set the field to null, I just can't figure out how to also allow this through the HTML form.

Said in pictures:

I currently have: [image: got]

I want to get to: [image: want]

Answer (score 2):

Found it. Simplified:

```
class SwitchPortSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    def get_fields(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = super(SwitchPortSerializer, self).get_fields(*args, **kwargs)
        fields['switch'].empty_label = ''
        return fields
```